# Are these quotient modules isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

> Let $K$ be an algebraic number field and $\mathcal{O}_K$ its ring of integers. For a non-zero ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ of $\mathcal{O}_K$ and an element $c \in \mathcal{O}_K \setminus \{0\}$ I wonder whether we always have an isomorphism
>    $$ \mathfrak{a} / c \mathfrak{a} \cong \mathcal{O}_K / (c) $$
>   as $\mathcal{O}_K$-modules.

Using the inverse (fractional) ideal $\mathfrak{a}^{-1}$, one could naïvely "calculate"
$$ \mathfrak{a} / (c) \mathfrak{a} \cong \mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{a}^{-1} / (c)\mathfrak{a}\mathfrak{a}^{-1} = \mathcal{O}_K / (c)\mathcal{O}_K = \mathcal{O}_K / (c). $$
But (again) I do not know how to justify the isomorphism.

**Additonal question**

**Is it easier to somehow only show $ [\mathfrak{a} : c \mathfrak{a}] = [\mathcal{O}_K : (c)]$ ?** This would help me, too :-).

Comment: for sure they are when $K$ has class number $1$, since if $\mathfrak a$ is principal then $\mathcal O_K\simeq \mathfrak a$ as $\mathcal O_K$-modules.

Comment: It may help to note that if $\mathfrak a$ and $(c )$ are coprime, then this follows from the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: May I also invite you to have a look at [point (2) of my answer (to my own question) over here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1404011/247396)? Although this being of own interest to me, that is the original context where the question arose. Maybe it is even easier to answer it in that particular setting?

Comment: @Mathmo123: If we had $c \notin \mathfrak{a}$, could we somehow deduce $\mathfrak{a}$ and $(c)$ being coprime?

Comment: @puck29 not necessarily. For example, in $\mathbb Z$, $6\notin (9)$. However, if $\mathfrak a$ is prime, then this will be true.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is yes, but this is not trivial, and the isomorphism is not canonical (it depends on some choice). Actually this is true for every Dedekind domain $R$. Firstly, I state you a lemma:

> Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain, $\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{b} \subset R$ ideals of $R$. Then there exists $\alpha \in \mathfrak{a}$ such that $$\alpha \mathfrak{a}^{-1} + \mathfrak{b} = R$$

Apply this lemma to $\mathfrak{a}, (c)$. So there exists $\alpha \in \mathfrak{a}$ such that $$\alpha \mathfrak{a}^{-1} + (c) = R$$
multiplying by $\mathfrak{a}$ we get the relation
$$(\alpha ) + (c)\mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{a}$$
from which we deduce that $\alpha \notin c\mathfrak{a}$.

Now, define the map
$$\begin{matrix} f : &R& \to & \mathfrak{a} / c\mathfrak{a} \\
&x& \mapsto & \alpha x+ c\mathfrak{a} \end{matrix}$$
should be surjective, and the kernel should be $(c)$. Hence $f$ induces an isomorphism
$$R/(c) \cong \mathfrak{a} / c\mathfrak{a} $$

Comment: Thanks @Crostul :-). I still have to understand some things. It's clear to me why $f$ is surjective. As for the kernel, at the moment I only get $(c) \subseteq \ker(f)$. But why does $\alpha x \in c\mathfrak{a}$ already imply $x \in (c)$?

Comment: By the way: When deducing $ \alpha \notin c\mathfrak{a} $ we assume w.l.o.g. that $c$ is not a unit of $\mathcal{O}_K$, right? And that's okay, because otherwise my question would be trivial ;-).

Comment: I also would be interested to read a proof of the stated lemma later. Maybe someone can point me to a good source?

Comment: @puck29 : see e.g. lemma 1.8 in _Introduction to Algebraic K-theory_ (Milnor)...

Answer (score 3):

> Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain and $I,J$ two nonzero ideals of $R$. Then $$I/JI\simeq R/J.$$

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1074748/121097) I've shown that there is an ideal $I'$ such that $I\simeq I'$ and $I'+J=R$. But $I\simeq I'$ [is equivalent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37547/proving-that-isomorphic-ideals-are-in-the-same-ideal-class) to $\exists x\in Q(R)$, $x\ne 0$ such that $I'=xI$. (Here $Q(R)$ denotes the field of fractions of $R$.) From $xI+J=R$ we get $xI\cap J=xIJ$. Then $$R/J=(xI+J)/J\simeq xI/xI\cap J=xI/xIJ\simeq I/IJ.$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is another proof for the more general $I/IJ \cong R/J$ proposed in the answer above:

The statement certainly holds if $I$ is principal. Locally, $R$ is a PID, hence the statement is true after localization at any maximal ideal.

$R/J$ is artinian, hence semi-local. Over a semi-local ring, we can test two finitely-presented modules to be isomorphic by testing them to be isomorphic locally (Without any global homomorphism given!). This is *Exercise 4.13* in Eisenbud's "Commutative Algebra with a View...".

Thus $R/J \cong I/IJ$ as $R/J$-modules and subsequently also as $R$-modules.